# different Header/Footer on first/last/odd/even pages in puppeter-sharp

Tags: html, pdf, razor, puppeteer-sharp

I use puppeteer-shrap to generate PDF.

I use FooterTemplate of pdfOptions to generate document Footer, and so HeaderTemplate to generate Header.

https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.PdfOptions.html

Is possible to use different Header/Footer on specific page?
One for first page, last page, odd pages, even pages and custom ranges.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sadly, you can't do that

Comment: @hardkoded Is possible to check PageNumber in Footer and rely on it change some layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a horrible hack (taken from this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2089#issuecomment-379934407)) to remove the header on the first page.

> The following puppeteer code solved my problem. It adds a style tag which collapses the margin-top on the first page (effectively hiding the margin). It then adds a margin-top to the body, to put a visible margin back into place.

```cs
await page.AddStyleTagAsync(new AddTagOptions
{
    Content = "@page:first {margin-top: 0;} body {margin-top: 1cm;}"
});
```